# Getting Building iOS bundle error when trying to build an android app - expo -react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I was able to build app using `expo build:android` previously. However, after upgrading to latest expo version I get following error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I also see the following lines in the log:

```
Publishing to channel 'default'...
Building iOS bundle
```

I don't added ios to my app.json, I only need to build an android apk. To do that I use `expo build:android -t app-bundle`

I also removed `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and run npm install, but I get the same error.

I run `expo start` on another cmd and then run `expo build:android -t app-bundle` still get same error

Also when I clear expo cache, see the following log:

```
Restarting Metro Bundler...
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: Invalid source port: 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same issue myself and found the solution. Expo is looking for **localhost:19001** which is not running. Just follow following steps and it should work as expected:

1. Run `expo start` no terminal and once it opens up the
   browser where you will find this line written *Starting Metro
   Bundler on port 19001*.
2. Now open another terminal instance and run `expo build:android`.

Comment: actually I removed npm cache and re-build every thing and it worked perfectly, I thing in updating expo something went wrong

Comment: Good to hear you got the solution.